# How to verify if user is a student on Android application

Tags: android, verification, mobile-application

I am working on an Android application that will have something like subscriptions (monthly, half yearly, yearly etc). The business logic is that there are discounts for students (school, college). Is there proper way to verify that someone is student? I think that Isic cards are international document for proving that someone is student, but is it secure enough? What are your thoughts?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific programming issues and problems related directly to code. This does not really meet those guidelines.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! This is a programming issue.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way different websites use to verify if a person belongs to a university/college is by regsitering them with their University/ college email id. Usually the college emails end with ac.in/.edu, etc. So, you can use these facts to verify that. However, i didn't know if you will be able to verify if the person is indeed a student from the University or just another official.

Comment: In my case the subscription renewals every year which means that every year the user has to verify that he/she is a student. For example transit cards for students and non students